# System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyBlogSite.Models.BlogPost>' does not contain a definition for 'Categories'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my BlogPost Model class:

```
    public class BlogPost
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    public string PostBody { get; set; }

    public string Meta { get; set; }
    public string UrlSlug { get; set; }        
    public DateTime PostedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BlogPostCategory> Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BlogPostTag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my BlogPostCategory Model class:

```
    public class BlogPostCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UrlSlug { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    // Decared virtual because the data must be returned from another table.
    public virtual ICollection<BlogPost> BlogPosts { get; set; }
}
```

Each class belongs to a separate Controller/View.

Finally, here is the top port of the Index View for Blog:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyBlogSite.Models.BlogPost>

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }

@Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Category/_Categories.cshtml", Model.Categories );

<p>
   @Html.ActionLink("New Blog Post", "Create")
</p>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
    </th>
    ....
```

In the View where Model.Categories is being passed in is where I am getting the exception from the title of this post. It seems to me that I have defined Categories within the BlogPost Model. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Model on your Razor page is an `IEnumerable<MyBlogSite.Models.BlogPost>`. It seems you're trying to display the information about each of the items in your collection. If so, then you can loop through them or create a display/editor template and use `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x)` or `@Html.EditorFor(x => x)`, respectively.

```
@foreach(var post in Model) {
    <p>Do stuff here with the local "post" variable.</p>
}
```

Here's [a link to Scott Gu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/19/asp-net-mvc-3-new-model-directive-support-in-razor.aspx) talking about the `@model` directive in Razor views.